# Current directory is invalid if you remove it and mkdir it again

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, mkdir

When user in a current directory e.g. "/home/test" in Ubuntu bash, if user remove this directory and create it again with another bash, then the directory in old bash is invalid. But it's valid in new bash. can somebody explain why it's happen?

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The files in the Linux filesystem are not identified by their path, but by their [inode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inode). The new directory has the same path, but it is not the same directory. Your shell is confused that it has a reference to a directory that does not exist any more; the fact that there is another directory with the same path doesn't matter to it. If you do `cd $(pwd)` in the invalid directory (i.e. re-enter it), it will be found as valid.

Imagine talking to your boss about the promotion. The next day the boss got dumped and replaced by someone else. You go ask your boss about the promotion, and he says "I have no idea what you're talking about". Both your old boss and your new boss are your boss; but not the same person. Same thingy.

---

Here's a fun experiment to show this inode-vs-filename difference:

```
( echo foo ; mv test.txt test2.txt ; echo bar ) > test.txt
```

One would naively expect that we'd have `test2.txt` with `foo` and `test.txt` with `bar` (we write `foo` to `test.txt`, it gets moved, then we write `bar` to `test.txt`). But this produces a file `test2.txt` with `foo` and `bar`. The reason is that the redirection opens `test.txt` for writing, which involves looking up the path and finding the inode that is assigned to the path, storing it in the file descriptor. From then on, only the file descriptor is used to write (and consequently the inode). When we change the directory entry from `test.txt` to `test2.txt`, it does not affect the inode.

So what happens is, we look up `test.txt`, get inode, write `foo` to that inode, change the directory entry to reflect the change in the file name, write `bar` to the same inode. This is like chatting with your boss; boss getting fired; but you find him at home and continue chatting with him. His title may have changed, but he's still the same person.

Comment: As i understand when  user remove a directory, the meta data of directory are changed and filesystem free up the inode of the directory, hence bash can not find related inode of directory and new directory with same path has new own inode. I checked by {stat /home/test} command  and then after removing /home/test the {find -inum [xxxxxxxx]}  return nothing. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Yep, that's the long and short of it. :)